# HTTP authentication error when sending email from behind the proxy

Tags: python, email, proxy

I am using the below python code and It is throwing 
HTTPError: 407: authenticationrequired.

I am passing the correct email id and password, but still the issue persists. Any thoughts why i am seeing this error

```
socks.set_default_proxy(socks.HTTP,'proxy.proxy.com',9090,True,userid,pwd)
socks.wrapmodule(smtplib)

smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 587
sender_email = "abc@gmail.com"
password = "pwd"
message = "Test message from python"
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
server.starttls()
server.login(sender_email,password)
server.sendmail(sender_email, "xxx@gmail.com", message)
server.quit()
```

Comment: It sounds like your proxy wants to be authenticated against as well, i.e. anonymous relay is not allowed